# joomla helix 3 simple image holder doesnt align center

Tags: templates, joomla

I am designing a new site... using Helix 3 template.
And Simple Image holder module.
I set the in the module setting allign - center but the image always appears on the left.

I guess there its something that has to do with the layout settings in Helix 3.
Can anyone help please..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sharing a link to the live website might help elicit useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put css style on image insert on it `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;`